# Incomplete D Drive access on which Ubuntu is installed

Tags: wubi

I have installed Ubuntu using Wubi on my Windows partition (D Drive). However, I cannot access the rest of the files on my D Drive other than the "host' files of my Ubuntu installation. System monitor indicates that my drive is fuselblk. How should I go about accessing the rest of my files on my D Drive?

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/host/`. Your D Drive files, except of Ubuntu installation should be there.